# How to store Qt console output into text file from command line in Ubuntu

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu

I wrote a Qt application which runs in Ubuntu Background as a Daemon. This application  crashes after a random time, I want to see what error it gives when it crashesh.

I wrote this syntax to see if I can get its output in a text:

```
dimit@dimit-FX620DX:~$ ./Myapp &> DebugInfo.txt
```

but it doesn't write anything in the text file. I wrote this simple program to simulate the bigger project

Mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    std::vector<int> Test;
    Test[-1] = 90;  //in here it gives segmentation fault error and exits the program
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

here is the output of the terminal when I run this code:

```
dimit@dimit-FX620DX:~/QtProjects/Test/Test-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1__System__Debug$ ./Myapp  &> DebugInfo.txt
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I expected to see "Aborted (core dumped)" in the DebugInfo.txt file but nothing were written in it. What should I do ?

I'm using Qt 4.8 under Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: You want to forward the *standard error* of your process to a file, not the *standard output*. That means `2>` instead of `>`

Comment: yeah but putting & before > means both standard output and standard error.

Comment: Remove spaces between &> and DebugInfo.txt and i would use it in that order >&

Comment: @Dimitry Hm, interesting, didn't know that one. I thought you want to execute it as a job *and* forwarding the output to a file.

Comment: @Maciej it didn't change anything ... I think bash handles white spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Aborted (core dumped)" text is not printed by your program, it's printed by the shell *after* program terminates. So, solution is simple, run the program in another shell, and redirect it's output:

```
sh -c ./Myapp &> DebugInfo.txt
```

(The `-c` makes the shell execute the command as a command line, and is needed because without it `sh` would try to run `./Myapp` as a shell script and fail.)

Comment: Now I can understand why users with high reputation has more ability to solve the problems than others ;)